# How to use Connect-AzAccount in a Powershell Runbook with an AutomationConnection

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-rm

All the examples I can find for Authenticating a Runbook use the AzureRM modules:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
```

However, if you are using the new Az Modules, this code does not work AND you cannot mix **AzureRM Modules** AND **Az Modules** in the same Runbook. How do you get authentication to work with the new Az Modules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This block can be used to Authenticate in a Runbook.
Be sure to follow module configuration instructions:
[Az module support in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/az-modules)

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "

    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    $connectionResult =  Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
                             -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID   `
                             -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
                             -ServicePrincipal
    "Logged in."

}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```